# How can I use SET in MYSQL to combine 2 values?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I wanted to SET a value into a VARCHAR but I don't understand how to combine it.

```
DECLARE id INTEGER;
DECLAR action VARCHAR(100);
SET id = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Test.Test);
SET action = "This is a test" + id;
```

Somehow I am losing the textpart "This is a test".
Is this normal behaviour for MySQL, am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: + is an arithmetic operator in mysql - use concat

Comment: This is what I needed. I approached it like I would in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL functions.
SET action = CONCAT('This is a test',id);

Comment: Worked like a charm! I was approaching it like I would do with C#.